# Can I get homebrew autocompletion in powershell?

Tags: macos, powershell, homebrew, psreadline

I used to use zsh, but I've got some cross-platform scripts written in `pwsh`. As a macOS user, I use `homebrew` constantly. The thing bothers me most is that `homebrew` official doesn't provide `pwsh` autocompletion. How can I get one?

Answer (score -1):

Comes bundled with powershell 7. You need to import PSReadline in your powershell profile, then map a key to autocomplete. Latest versions of PS also have history and plugin based intellisense (with only one plugin for the latter), which also has to be enabled in your profile.

Comment: PSReadlines' predictive intellisense WILL autocomplete assuming you've typed it out manually at least once, and gone through the steps to activate it. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-psreadline-2-1-with-predictive-intellisense/

Comment: In this case, homebrew autocompletion in PSReadline is astonishing terrible comparing to zsh. Looks like you never really try these thing!

Comment: Never said it was good, but it's what there is for powershell. If you want to downgrade to using base windows powershell, then there's powertab.